# Using Google Photos or another service to host photos from mobile app on android

Tags: android, google-photos

I have a mobile app and want to use something like 'cloudinary' and 'imageshack', which will allow me to upload photos taken by users to the cloud and share them with the others. Can I achieve something like this using Google Photos API (or another Google service)? Is it even possible using Google services?

Answer (score 1):

You can use firebase to do this. Upload the photos into storage, and put the urls inside the real time database, so other users can access them. But this is not a free solution as you would have to pay after you get over certain limits of usage.

Comment: Interesting. But then probably I have to handle everything by myself. I mean for example getting thumbnails (which isn't hard to add). But if I want to have a moderator, which will approve or reject user photos I'd have to create some sort of app to do it.

Comment: Yeah, you would have to handle all the logic of showing images, approving, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although i would not recommend that you rely on a the 'photos' app for your apps content sink and media provider, you could delegate to google photos and to their free cloud in the following way:

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

review the link for receiving data in your app from "google photos" ....

and maybe review general link : https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services

Details on using 'photos' app in your app as a sink and as a provider.

If a user has your app & 'photos' installed then whenever your app invokes a chooser on the correct mime types, "google photos" will be included in the list of possible choosers presented by UI & content provider selection list ** see photo.
[image]

Regarding "chooser" intents on mime types of "image/*"  or on "video/*" 
when your app signals the intent to get content ( images or videos ) the corresponding manifest in the photos app will result in that apps appearance as a provider ( see photo ) and you can work with media from the google cloud.

When you delegate the chooser to photos and have it return a reference, it may then be a somewhat involved process to 'filter the feed' of that third party cloud photo for a public url which you can substitute in place of a photo URI from your on persistence layer. Example would be : https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipNWZGgaA38jNrHrE9uBvupzQimhzZy5rOiEE2cN